# how to hide a button in ajax response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, modal-dialog

I am using an ajax call inside my javascript page.Below is my ajax call...

```
$("#txn_post").dialog({
        modal: true,
        title:"Transaction",
        show: 'blind',
        hide: 'blind',
        width: 740,
        height:550,
            });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/pms/txn/newTax",
        success: function (response) {
            /*$("#txn_post").hide();*/
            alert("resp");
            $("#txn_post").html(response);
            alert("after resp");
            //$('#txn_delete_btn').hide();
            //$("#txn_div").dialog("open"); 
            //with out excecuting my above code my dialog works
            /*$("#txn_delete_btn").attr("disabled", false);*/
        }
    });
```

the modal shows,but i tried many way to hide a button inside the modal.But it does not effect......

The code onwards `$("#txn_post").html(response);` inside my success of ajax doesnot get excecuted.

```
<div id="txn_post" class="currencydiv" style="width: auto; display: none; min-height: 0px; max-height: none; height: 570px;"></div>
```

is the div of modal and

`<input class="pms_void_btn_trnsction txn_delete_btn " id="txn_delete_btn" value="DELETE" onclick="deleteField('${currentTxnNo}');" type="button"></input>` is my delete button that i needed to hide.

How to hide the above button from my ajax success?Any help will be highly appreciable.

Comment: @COdekid.php that part of code is commented"because its not excecuted".

Comment: html is invalid .. there is no `</input>` ... it is a self closing tag and you use `val()` to set value not `html()`

Comment: @charlietfl after showing my modal,my delete button wont hides,is any special cases for coding inside ajax response(i am new to jquery)?

Comment: No special cases. Are you sure the `success` is even firing?

Comment: @charlietfl: yeah beacuse alert("resp");
            $("#txn_post").html(response);  steps are excecuted.

Comment: What is in the `response`? And where is `#txn_delete_btn` is it in the dialog?

Comment: response is showing dialog and #txn_delete_btn doesnot hides.I need to hide it .

Comment: If you want to hide the dialog, why not juse close it? $("#txn_post").dialog('close');

Comment: @Edgar: I dont want to hide the dialog,i just want to hide a button inside my dialogue

Comment: @Miller if that button is inside of `response`, you can just hide it with `display: none;`, if its not in `response`, $('#txn_delete_btn').hide(); should work

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#txn_post").dialog({
    modal: true,
    title:"Transaction",
    show: 'blind',
    hide: 'blind',
    width: 740,
    height:550,
        });

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/pms/txn/newTax",
    success: function (response) {
        $("#txn_post").html(response);
        $("#txn_post").find('#txn_delete_btn').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

If you still have trouble, you can make sure you're getting the correct objects by trying `alert($("#txn_post").attr('id'));` and `alert($("#txn_post").find('#txn_delete_btn').attr('id'));`